# Adjacent Sibling Not Working - CSS3 Selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to make `:hover` changes on child element.

Let's say I have the below HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="adjacent_sibling">Placeholder text</div>
    <div class="adjacent_sibling class">Placeholder text</div>
</div>
```

I can make changes on the child element with CSS like this:

```
.wrap:hover .class {
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

but can't I make changes like this:

```
.wrap:hover + .wrap > .adjacent-sibling{
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

or:

```
.wrap:hover + .adjacent-sibling {
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

How can this be achieved?
I need to target the **adjacent sibling** if it is the child (children). This is for learning purposes only.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You need to read [basics](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Comment: Read it long time ago. I need to target the adjacent sibling if it is the child (children).

Comment: "I need to target the adjacent sibling if it is the child" - it can only be either a sibling, or a child. Both together is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`+`** Refers to the neighbor element and not to children.

**If you want its need to be like this:**

```
.wrap:hover > .adjacent-sibling,
.wrap > .adjacent-sibling {
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

---

**or:**

```
.wrap:hover > .adjacent-sibling {
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

---

**Edit:** How target adjacent siblings in the children:

```
.wrap:hover > .adjacent-sibling + .adjacent-sibling.class {
/*CSS to come here*/
}
```

Comment: I have already wrote this. How can I target adjacent siblings in the children?

Comment: @stormec56 You nedd to use `child-selector` as @Zeev Katz said above.

Comment: And that is the answer to my question! thanks mate. :)

Comment: Edit my answer my friend

Comment: `+` does not refer to the *next*, but the **neighbor** element.